# QDockWidget will not show contents

Tags: qt, widget

I am attempting to create a specialised `QDockWidget`, with some contents, that I can use in other Qt5 UIs. To do this, I have created a `QDockWidget` subclass complete with a UI form, called `SpecialDockWidget`. The contents (a `QTreeWidget`) are added in the UI form.

In my main UI, I have added `SpecialDockWidget` as a `QDockWidget` promotion, have promoted the desired dock widget, and everything compiles OK. However, when I run the application my promoted dock widget contains the title of the `SpecialDockWidget` in its title bar, but the contents remain empty. This only happens if the dock widget is made part of the main UI (whether floating or attached), and the dock widget displays the contents successfully if it is instantiated on its own as a top-level widget.

The Qt documentation says the following with regards to `QDockWidget::setWidget()`:

> If the dock widget is visible when widget is added, you must `show()` it explicitly.
>
> Note that you must add the layout of the widget before you call this function; if not, the widget will not be visible.

I have tried calling `show()` on both the `SpecialDockWidget` and the contents, and have set the layout myself, but the contents still don't show up.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: Some photos showing what's going on:

[image: UI form for the dock widget]

[image: How the main UI turns out - title bar is included, contents are not.]

[image: Using the dock widget as a top-level widget is fine.]

Dock widget code:

```
#include "specialdockwidget.h"
#include "ui_specialdockwidget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>

SpecialDockWidget::SpecialDockWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SpecialDockWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

SpecialDockWidget::~SpecialDockWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Main window code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

//    This produces the top-level dock widget
//    SpecialDockWidget* w = new SpecialDockWidget();
//    w->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Post some code to show how the widget and its content is created

Comment: The site now constantly overwrites my edits, so: Image 1 - dock widget UI form. Image 2 - end result of main window. Image 3 - dock widget as a top-level widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QDockWidget` is created in the Designer so it's not very clear how the tree is added to the `QDockWidget`. If the tree is simply a child of the `QDockWidget` it's not correct. You must add the tree to the `QDockWidget` using `QDockWidget::setWidget()`.

I suggest to not use the Designer to create a subclass of `QDockWidget` because it seems not possible to add the content correctly. You can do something like this instead.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QDockWidget *dw = new QDockWidget(this);
    QTreeWidget* tw = new QTreeWidget(dw);
    dw->setWidget(tw);
    addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dw);
    dw->show();
}
```

Of course, if you need to put inside a dock widget a more complex widget, you can create the content with the Designer as a simple `QWidget` subclass and add it to the dock widget in the same way.

Comment: This seems to work, and should be good enough for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is strange indeed. If I add a `QDockWidget` with the designer and promote it to my derived class, it calls the constructor and creates a blank widget with the proper title text, but none of the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main window's constructor should look like, for example:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    SpecialDockWidget *w = new SpecialDockWidget();
    // Add dock widget to the specified area of main window.
    addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, w);
}
```

Comment: So it should be added here instead, and not added in the MainWindow UI form?

Comment: @x6herbius, I never did that in Qt Designer and even not sure it's possible. The proposed code demonstrates how I would do this myself.

Comment: I was planning to do as much through Designer as possible, which is just the way I listed above where the QDockWidget was promoted. I'll try your way and see if it works.